# How to reset to the state before a given git commit?

Tags: git

I have a big repository with some-hundred commits.

Given is the hash to a specific commit deep in down the history where something was fixed.
I know that I can revert to that commit by using

```
git reset 56e05fced214c44a37759efa2dfc25a65d8ae98d
```

However, I want the state BEFORE that fix was applied, i.e. one commit earlier.

(Now, in SVN I would just revert to the previous revision number but I know with GIT and all its distributed character that's not so easy).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do `git reset 56e05fced214c44a37759efa2dfc25a65d8ae98d^`

The `^` selects the commit previous.  You can also go any number of commits by using `~`. For two commits, it would be `git reset 56e05f~2`